# How can I configure HTTPS on AWS ECS container created with "ecs-cli"?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, https

Hi I configure Prisma GraphQL API server user docker-compose file with the command: `ecs-cli compose up --create-log-groups --cluster-config myapp-api --ecs-profile myapp-api-profile`.

**docker-compose.yml** file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '443:443'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 443
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: some-url.rds.amazonaws.com
            database: masvino-db
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: password
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql: ~
```

Containers are running like you can see here:

```
$ ecs-cli ps --cluster-config myapp-api --ecs-profile myapp-api-profile
Name                                         State    Ports                      TaskDefinition  Health
2ca71c7d-b402-45f8-ac86-12b0b9b5ab89/prisma  RUNNING  34.210.43.29:443->443/tcp  Server:2        UNKNOWN
2ca71c7d-b402-45f8-ac86-12b0b9b5ab89/mysql   RUNNING                             Server:2        UNKNOWN
```

Now, how can I configure the prisma container to use HTTPS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `34.210.43.29:443->443` means it runs on the HTTPS port. Wouldn't this question be better suited to networking? If 443 is unreachable, a firewall could be blocking the port.

Comment: Talking to a colleague I realize that service has to be on the port 80 and I have to put a load balancer that redirects traffic from HTTPS to HTTP. Load balancer has configurations for the necessary certificates. When I get it working I would post the finally solution.